# Could not find or load the main class WhileDemo error on cmd

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code written in notepad using cmd but While I compile this program it compiles successfully and creates a `WhileDemo.class` file also but when I execute this using command :`java WhileDemo`

I get the following error

> Error : could not find or load the main class `WhileDemo` I want to
>   use command: `java WhileDemo`

How can i do that?

```
class WhileDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int count = 1;
        while (count < 11) {
            System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're executing `java WhileDemo` in the directory where the `WhileDemo.class` file is stored?

Comment: Did you create the class in the default package, did you use `package <somename>;` perhaps?

Comment: @NicolasCarlo: yes i'm sure that i'm in right directory.But not working command : java WhileDemo for execution.

Answer (score 1):

```
set classpath=.
java WhileDemo
```

You need to set classpath and tell java where the class is. The dot (.) means look in whatever is the current directory.

Comment: You can also write `java -cp . WhiteDemo` if you want a simple one-liner.

Comment: @kajacx yes command : java -cp . WhileDemo works but why not java WhileDemo working?

Answer (score 0):

First, the `classpath` system variable tells java where to look for the program you want to run, that means if you write `java WhileDemo` into console, java will look into every directory in `classpath` (it can contain multiple directories separated with `;`, with both absolute and relative paths) if it contains `WhileDemo.class` file and if yes, it runs your program.

Now if you don't have `.` (current directory) in your `classpath` variable, you cannot expect java to find your `WhileDemo` program, even if you are executing the `java WhileDemo` command from the same directory.

**Solution**

1. As @user93353 said, you can replace the contents of class path by writing `set classpath=.` in your console, but this change will last only as long as the console is open.
2. You can add some directories to your classpath using the `-cp` option.
3. You can permanently change contens of the system `classpath` variable (i belive you can google how to do so), but in windows these changes will take effect after opening a new console window.

Sorry for so long answer, i'm bored and have nothing else to do.